# Subscribe method not working angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hi I have a angular 2 service which is returning me a SelectListItem[] but when I call the subscribe method on the component where I am using this service it is not able to assign the result to component property .Although if i console.log the output of subscribe it result the SelectListItem[].Below is the component where I am calling the method I am adding screen shot of the console where we can see the service returned some data.

```
export class SelectListItem {
constructor(id: number,
    name: string) { }
}
```

// component

```
        import {SelectListItem} from '../models/selectListItem';
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute }       from '@angular/router';
    import { InformationRequestService } from './informationrequest.service';
    import {MileStoneService} from '../mileStone/milestone.service';
    import {MileStoneModel} from '../models/milestoneModel';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
    import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
    @Component(
        {
            moduleId: module.id,
            templateUrl: './addinformationrequest.html'    ,
            providers: [InformationRequestService,MileStoneService]
        }
    )
    export class AddInformationRequestComponenet implements OnInit {

        mileStonedataSourceList: SelectListItem[];   
        selectedMileStone: number;
        selectedRecepient: number;
        errorMessage: string;
        milestomes: MileStoneModel[];
        form: FormGroup;
        constructor(private inforService: InformationRequestService, private mileStoneService: MileStoneService) {
            this.inforService = inforService; this.mileStoneService = mileStoneService;

        }

        ngOnInit() {

            this.form = new FormGroup({
                Id: new FormControl(),
                InformationRequired: new FormControl(),
                StartDate: new FormControl()
            });        
            this.getMileStones();
           // console.log(this.errorMessage);

        }

        getMileStones() {       

            this.mileStoneService.getSelectListMilestones().subscribe((t) => {
                this.mileStonedataSourceList = t;
             **// on console i see 13 objects returned by service but this.mileStonedataSourceList is not assigned**
             console.log(t);
            }); 



        }
        onMileStoneSelect(selectedItem) {

            this.selectedMileStone = selectedItem;
            console.log(this.selectedMileStone);
        }
    }
```

// addinformationRequest.html

```
<br /> <br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="md-col-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"> Add Information</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="saveMileStone()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="md-col-4">
                            <label>Information Required:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="md-col-4">
                            <input formControlName="InformationRequired" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="md-col-4"><label> MileStone Date</label></div>
                        <div class="md-col-4">
                                             <ng-dropDown [dataSourceList]="mileStonedataSourceList" 
                                             [(ngModel)]="selectedMileStone" 
                                             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

                                             (onSelectItem)="onMileStoneSelect($event)"
                                             ngDefaultControl></ng-dropDown>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group" aria-label="...">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Cancel</button>
                        &nbsp;

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                {{ newMileStone|json }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// The Directive which I am using

```
    import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
    import {NgModel, ControlValueAccessor} from "@angular/forms";
    import {SelectListItem} from '../models//SelectListItem';

    @Component({
        selector: 'ng-dropDown[ngModel]',
        //  directives: [NgIf, NgFor, NgClass],
        template: `
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
                   <select (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)"   name="dd"  class="form-control" [id]="refId">

                  <option *ngFor="let item of dataList"  [value]="item.id">
                         {{item.name}}
                      </option>    
                    </select>
    </div>
    `
    })

    export class DropDownDirective implements OnInit {
        @Input("dataSourceList") dataSourceList: SelectListItem[];
        @Input("Id") Id: string;
        dataList: SelectListItem[];
        selectedOption: number;
        refId: string;

        @Output("onSelectItem") onSelectItem = new EventEmitter();

        ngOnInit() {
            this.refId = this.Id;
           // console.log("lll" + this.dataSourceList.length);
            this.createSelectList();
        }

        constructor(private selectedOptionModel: NgModel) {
            //    this.selectedOptionModel.valueAccessor = this;

        }
        onSelect(selectedId) {
            console.log("selected option:" + selectedId);
            this.onSelectItem.emit(selectedId);
        }


        createSelectList() {
            this.dataList = this.dataSourceList;
        }



    }
```

// the mileStoneService method which I am using to return 
            getSelectListMilestones(): Observable {

```
                        return this.http.get(this.url)
                            .map((response: Response) => <MileStoneModel[]>response.json())
                            .map((mileStones: MileStoneModel[]) => {
                             return    mileStones.map(mileStone => new SelectListItem(mileStone.Id, mileStone.Name));
                            })                               
                            .catch(this.handleError);
                    }
```

// changed code in addinformationRequest.html ...

```
            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
                                <select  name="dd" class="form-control" [id]="refId">

                                    <option *ngFor="let item of mileStonedataSourceList" [value]="item.id">
                                        {{item.name}}
                                    </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

here is HTML source in screen shot.[image]

Comment: Can you please try `setTimeout(() => this.mileStonedataSourceList = t;)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried didn't worked

Comment: Where and how do you verify that the values were (not) assigned?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer :this property is binded to the drop down list . I have a directive and I am assinging this property to the input of directive.And as you can see in the screen shot drop down is filled .

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error lies there. Can you please add this code?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : this is how I am using the SelectListItem directive/component .   <ng-dropDown [dataSourceList]="mileStonedataSourceList" 
                                                 [(ngModel)]="selectedMileStone" 
                                                 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                             
                                                 (onSelectItem)="onMileStoneSelect($event)"
                                                 ngDefaultControl></ng-dropDown>

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: What is shown when you add `<div>{{mileStonedataSourceList | json}}</div>` instead of `<ng-dropDown>`? Are you sure the selector is `ng-dropDown` not `ng-dropdown`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : I think selector is fine . Because it worked when I tested it with a hardcoded values . And the {mileStonedataSourceList | json}} return nothing .Shall I post the mileStoneService  code as well ?

Comment: I can't tell whether the selector is correct because I don't know what `ng-dropDown` component you're using. I don't need the service code if you say that  the `console.log()` prints the values.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : I posted the code of the ng-dropDown component in the question as well .

Comment: No idea. I can't imagine if the `console.log()` prints the data like shown in your screenshot that `{{mileStonedataSourceList | json}}` doesn't show it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : I console.log(t) . not console.log (this.mileStonedataSourceList).  if I try to log mileStonedataSourceList it says undefined .

Comment: `console.log(mileStonedataSourceList)` without `this.` is supposed to print `undefined`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: after adding settimeout as you mentioned . I did  console.log(this.mileStonedataSourceList) I know if I do only  mileStonedataSourceList it will show undefined .

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : this is strange as on saying {{mileStonedataSourceList | json}} inside div now shows  me something like [{},{}] with 13 elements present but no data inside just blank.

Comment: `[{},{}]` doesn't look like 13 elements. I also don't know what your code currently looks like or what your tried.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer :- The code is same present above just removed ng-dropDown directive and I didn't type all 13 curly braces but counted them they are repeated 13 times and this is the total count of items returned by service .

Comment: Then the data is assigned and your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer :I added the Service method code in question which I am trying to consume and return an Observale of selectListItem . what I am trying is the following . Call mileStoneService which return an array of MileStoneModel then transform this into SelectListItem so that I can use a common component for all dropdown may be you can guide me what is the right way of doing this . I tested the dropdown component with static array of selectListItem and it worked . So was assuming that either my component or service method is not working correctly .

Comment: Looks fine. . .  .

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: what I changed now is I put the html code for drop down in the same file and run the for loop . When I inspect the html It shows 13 elements but values are undefined . This brings me to the mileStoneService method I called I think it is not able to return proper SelectListItem . Can you please tell me how can I convert MileStoneModel[] to Observable SelectListItem  method name getSelectListMilestones it is in the question .

Comment: As I said, the code looks fine to me.